# CloudFormation -- possible to have nested Mappings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to have nested Mappings in CloudFormation, like the following example?

```
"Mappings" :  
{
    "Regions" : 
    {
        "us-east-1" : 
        {
            "Environments" :
            {
                "dev" : 
                {
                    "ImageId" : "something",
                    "Subnet" : "something"
                },
                "qa" :
                {
                    "ImageId" : "something",
                    "Subnet" : "something"
                }
            }
        },
        "us-west-2" : 
        {
            "Environments" :
            {
                "dev" : 
                {
                    "ImageId" : "something",
                    "Subnet" : "something"
                },
                "qa" :
                {
                    "ImageId" : "something",
                    "Subnet" : "something"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to do something like this, I get the following error:

> Template format error: Every Mappings attribute must be a String or a List.

If nested Mappings aren't possible, then what is the best way to store values in a CFT that require two parameters to select (such as values that depend on BOTH Region and environment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
"ImageMap" : {
    "us-east-1" : { "dev" : "ami-11111111", "qa" : "ami-22222222" },
    "us-west-1" : { "dev" : "ami-33333333", "qa" : "ami-44444444" }
 }
```

and then to access these values:

```
"Value" : {
    "Fn::FindInMap" : [
        "ImageMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, { "Ref" : "EnvironmentType" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to have multiple values listed under the same Mapping? Is there any way to avoid having separate Mappings for every value? I edited the OP for clarification.

Comment: Have not validated this but you might be able to set them up as follows: "us-east-1-dev" : { "imageid" : "abc", "subnet" : "xyz" } and then use Fn::Join to join the region ref and the environment ref creating something like us-east-1-dev or us-west-2-qa and that would form the first dimension for Fn::FindInMap, with "imagedid" or "subnet" being the 2nd dimension. Not ideal, but I do not believe that CF supports more than two dimensions in mappings.

Comment: that would definitely work, and it's nice knowing that there's a way to have an arbitrary number of parameters, but it is hackier than I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
"Mappings" :  
{
    "dev" : 
    {
        "us-east-1" :
        {
            "ImageId" : "something",
            "Subnet" : "something"
        },
        "us-west-2" :
        {
            "ImageId" : "something",
            "Subnet" : "something"
        }
    },
    "qa" : 
    {
        "us-east-1" :
        {
            "ImageId" : "something",
            "Subnet" : "something"
        },
        "us-west-2" :
        {
            "ImageId" : "something",
            "Subnet" : "something"
        }
    }
}
```

The important point here is that the objects alternate between "mappings" and keys". So in this situation, "dev" is a Mapping, "us-east-1" is a key, "ImageId" is a mapping, and "something" is a key. Mapping names cannot have non-alphanumeric characters, so Region names cannot be Mappings. Thus, using the environment as the first parameter and using the region name as the second parameter is mandatory.

It seems to me like the Mappings section of CloudFormation has a lot of really strange arbitrary rules, and it surprises me that it isn't more flexible, but there you have it.

Comment: how did then get the actual value?

Comment: doesn't the key have to be two levels?

Comment: It would be accessed like { “Fn:FindInMap” : [ “dev”, { “Ref” : “AWS::Region” }, “ImageId” ] }

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue. Found the following in the [Fn::FindInMap documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html)

> The intrinsic function Fn::FindInMap returns the value corresponding
> to keys in a **two-level map** that is declared in the Mappings
> section.

So basically:

The following will work:

```
Mappings:
    map_name:
        level_1_key:
            level_2_key:
                "value"
```

But 3 levels won't.

```
Mappings:
    map_name:
        level_1_key:
            level_2_key:
                level_3_key:
                    "value"
```